# Ranking users with MySQL from multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, database, ranking

I am trying to implement a ranking system in my website. What I am trying to do is the following:

Users can upload images and of course we track the views they get. So I want to implement a ranking system where there is a top 20 ranking of the images which are viewed the most in the last day (7 and 30 possibly). So what do I need for this? Well this is the following information:

- User ID
- File ID
- Total downloads/views

All of this information is located in a different column:

- User ID:  users > ID
- File ID:  file > id
- Total downloads/views: file >  visits

Desired output:

```
rank | File ID | User ID | Visits
  1  | 33      |  3      | 90
  2  | 34      |  4      | 70
  3  | 35      |  5      | 60
```

So can anybody help me how I can do this?

Check which files have had the most visits (in the last day), get the file ID's and then use these to locate the user ID's. The outcome would be put out in a table of course.

Comment: sqlfiddle.com some data so we have schema and show desired output

Comment: now is the desired output from one table or many tables? you'll have to show how where 90 comes from a single column or a count() of rows from another table...table schemas ... please

Comment: You need to provide some code of you trying, and show us where you get stuck @Imageman

Comment: It is from different tables, I am sorry if I am not explaining it clearly. File ID & visits are from the same table. I am not that good with MySQL yet.

Comment: show us your create table statements, surely to get past week there's gotta be some sort of date/time column involved too

Comment: There is not anything regarding date/time of views in the database. They get pulled with OnLoadJS. There is a stats page for every image, so it should be possible but I am having a hard time getting it clear in my mind. So for now the total views will do.